# To what "its" refers in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> This book challenges uncritical narratives of the Anthropocene that reproduce modernist and technocratic notions of nature and limit **its** abilities to generate a politics of global warming.([Source](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/archaeology/archaeological-theory-and-methods/climate-without-nature-critical-anthropology-anthropocene?format=HB#RP0DP0HuqEpij7hr.97))

Answer (score 2):

If we break the sentence down, its component parts are:

1. This book challenges uncritical narratives of the Anthropocene
2. These uncritical narratives reproduce modernist and technocratic notions of nature,
3. and these narratives limit **its** abilities to generate a politics of global warming.

I respectfully disagree with the first answer that *narratives* can limit a *narrative*.

I suggest that **its** in this context can only refer back to **nature**.

The sentence then says that these uncritical narratives have the joint effect of producing particular notions of nature and limiting nature's abilities to generate a politics of global warming.

At the end of the day, the author could have been a lot clearer.

Comment: nature generates politics?!

Comment: @user157323: To some people, absolutely. People that see this as perhaps a bit silly may well disagree with the authors in other ways.

Comment: Just noticed this: I think you could reasonably swap out "nature" for "Anthropocene" as the referent without changing the semantics you read this with, and that would also keep the sentence from referring to an internal part of a clause ("nature") in a modifying clause ("and limit **its** abilities"). Referring "its" back to "Anthropocene" should be grammatically a trifle less confused.

Comment: Imho the text itself is pretty rubbishy (*modernist and technocratic notions of nature* sounds like something from an eco-warrior who didn't pay attention in his English classes, and plural ***abilities*** just sounds clumsy here), so there's limited value in trying to analyse exactly how it all hangs together syntactically. But you're quite right - ***nature*** (perhaps capitalised and/or humanised as ***Mother Nature***) is the only credible referent for ***its***. At least the writer knew enough not to include an apostrophe though!

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear, Reading pragmatically, I ask myself what could "generate a politics of global warming"?

Politics is generated by people discussing a topic. The word that could mean discussions is "narratives".  I conclude that the most likely reference for "its" is "narratives". The other possibility "Anthropocene" or "nature" doesn't make practical sense: a geological period doesn't have abilities!

I realise that this breaks the singular/plural agreement, I suppose that must just be an error.

So I think that "*uncritical* narratives limit the narrative's ability to generate a politics of climate change". The authors think that there needs to be a *critical* narrative to fully generate a politics.